# Excel Library not registered

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013, ms-project

I have a newly-bought laptop. I installed it with Visual Studio 2013, Office 2013, and Project 2013. However, when I run my app, I have an error message:

> {"Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'.  This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'  failed due to the
>   following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))."}

What could have caused this?

Comment: You apparently forgot to install *Microsoft.Office.Interop*. They're not part of Windows or Office 2013. Find them on the MS site via Google.

Comment: I reinstalled MS Office 2013, same error, how to install interop? when i reinstall office, i can only see the list of all available apps, and I select them all (I assumed selecting all will get the interop you are telling) and I only have 1 single button "Install", then that's it. after installation same error

Comment: @Gilbert do exactly what Ken said... it's not part of office 2013, so reinstalling won't fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

As Ken White mentioned in the comments, the Microsoft.Office.Interop files are not part of Office 2013 or Visual Studio. They must be downloaded and installed separately. You can download the files from Microsoft's website.

If you have already installed the Microsoft.Office.Interop package and you're still receiving this error, you may need to explicitly specify the location to these files so that your application can find them. See more information [in this MSDN forums thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97439188-6230-4b84-9f3d-5a3b6285a48e/how-to-download-quotmicrosoftofficeinteropexcelquot?forum=vbgeneral).